# Git take number of files changes not show files in windows 10 , can push by git command line

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

[image: Get number of file changes only i can`t see compare and push]

can push by command line not show any file and make uninstall to git and install again same problem

Comment: Did my answer helped? Did you managed to find Git from your VScode?

Comment: Great! What did you do to solve the issue? Opening VSCode from your current Git repo was enough?

Comment: Make uninstalled to git , add extension to vscode gitLens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first what the Visual Studio command `Git > Show Git Output` returns.

Then try and open from your Visual Studio one file of your current local Git repository, and check if the "Source Control" view remains empty.

A better detection of the Git installation is discussed in [vscode issue 61491](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61491#issuecomment-575299435).

The OP [Andrew Emad Gabra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9057668/andrew-emad-gabra) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60134987/git-take-number-of-files-changes-not-show-files-in-windows-10-can-push-by-git#comment106450939_60134987) that installing the [GitLens extension](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens) helps.